# Tables in Report Builder

Tags: sql, reportbuilder

I have a query that returns the following data:

```
Company Severity    SubTotal    Total
A       low         604777      2917023
K       low         253850      1497324
E       low         1234336     1234336
A       high        451630      2917023
B       high        259880      2106841
A       med         451630      2917023
K       med         1243474     1497324
D       med         1219110     1219110
C       med         1224336     1224336
G       med         1224336     1224336
H       med         1219880     1219880
B       med         1245461     2106841
R       med         1219880     1219880
A       very high   384336      2917023
F       very high   1224134     1224134
B       very high   601500      2106841
```

I want to use report builder and build a table like this:

```
Company     very high   high    med     low     Total
A           384336      451630  451630  604777  2917023
...
```

I have wasted all day trying all possible combinations to achieve this and failed
Can someone guide which values should go in `Column Groups`, `Row Groups` and `Values`

Also, i would like to give background cell color to certain cells where the value exceeds a certain threshold

Comment: I am not familiar with Report Builder, but I can tell you what you are after is a PIVOT clause in your query. Also, I'm not sure why you have the `Total` column. It is repeated data for each `Company`, and looks like it could probably be deduced from summing up all of the subtotals, correct?

Comment: Yes, `Total` can be achieved by summing up. I dont have much data, 500 rows so I am not focusing on having optimal stricture and queries. Also, arranging the data into a table i want will have many empty cells.

Comment: I wouldn't pivot in the query, SQL pivots are limited.  Report Builder has far deeper pivoting abilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Can someone guide which values should go in `Column Groups`, `Row Groups` and `Values`* -> I assume you are using the table/matrix wizard. In that case:

Company  -> `Row Groups`

Severity -> `Column Groups`

SubTotal -> `Values`

I would not use Total, rather let the matrix sum up the sub totals for total

Answer (score 2):

Based on your query data (which I call SourceTable), you can use a PIVOT clause to put the data into the tabular form you are after. Give this a try:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT Company, Severity, SubTotal FROM My_Existing_Query) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(SubTotal)
    FOR Severity IN ('very high' AS Very_High, 'high' AS High, 
        'med' AS Medium, 'low' AS LOW)
) AS PivotTable
```